# OracleAPPS- Can not get correct results for Suppliers - Bank query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to fetch suppliers and bank details in Oracle apps. I am able to write a simple query where each supplier has a supplier site attached to it. Few of my sites doesn't have a record in table "iby_pmt_instr_uses_all". But even then I want to show them . So I am using the outer join on this table. But the issue is when I am putting this outer join condition, I am getting double the records in the query. I believe I am missing on some condition, but can not figure out which one.

```
SELECT *
  FROM apps.iby_pmt_instr_uses_all instrument,
       apps.iby_account_owners owners,
       apps.iby_external_payees_all payees,
       apps.iby_ext_bank_accounts ieb,
       apps.ap_supplier_sites_all asa,
       apps.ap_suppliers asp,
       apps.ce_bank_branches_v cbbv
 WHERE     owners.ext_bank_account_id = ieb.ext_bank_account_id
       AND owners.ext_bank_account_id = instrument.instrument_id(+)
       AND payees.ext_payee_id = instrument.ext_pmt_party_id(+)
       AND cbbv.branch_party_id = ieb.branch_id
       AND payees.payee_party_id = owners.account_owner_party_id
       AND payees.supplier_site_id = asa.vendor_site_id
       AND asa.vendor_id = asp.vendor_id
       AND asp.vendor_name = 'PANALYTICAL'
--and ieb.bank_account_num = asa.VENDOR_SITE_CODE
```

If I add `and ieb.bank_account_num = asa.VENDOR_SITE_CODE` this condition I get the correct record, but actually this is not the right join, because there is no relationship between these 2 columns, so this will fail for other suppliers.
Can you please suggest what additional join I can put , so that I get the right result.

Thanks

Comment: Start by using proper JOIN

Comment: What do you meant by proper join ? Am I missing something ? I am getting proper results from this query if there are any banks associated with the supplier site. It is only just that when the site is not associated to any banks then it doesn't give me right results.

Comment: Using [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) has been a de-facto standard for many many years now and for one thing it makes queries easier to read since it brings the join and the join-condition together